# initializing private member array w/ size as a class initialization parameter

Tags: c++

so I have an "Office" class for a program that i'm currently writing, and each "Office" has a certain number of tellers who are either busy or idle. I want to represent these tellers as a private int array of the Office class.
The problem I am having is that the number of tellers is a declaration parameter for the office class, so I can't just go

```
private: 
    int tellers[num_tellers];
```

I've tried different things with the constructors, but nothing seems to work. How do I do this properly? Everything I see online is using the new operator, but I have no interest in using a pointer for this.

thanks in advance

Comment: "but I have no interest in using a pointer for this." A principle that will serve you well. What you want is `std::vector<int>`; this hides the nasty pointer stuff and gives you a nice automatic interface to it instead.

Comment: Exactly. With vector, just make your constructor `MyClass(size_t size) : tellers(size){/*...*/}`.

Comment: on the topic of avoiding pointers... is it possible to initialize a class without using a pointer (the new operator)? If there is i can't find it online... = \      edit: yea i was thinking about that, but i sort-of wanted to use an array just on the principle that it won't be expanding/contracting. Not a big deal though

Comment: @user1647959, You mean `MyClass *obj = new MyClass;`? Just use `MyClass obj;`. If you need the advantages of heap allocation, consider the safer smart pointer approach. C++11 introduces `std::unique_ptr`, which is a good general choice, and C++03 still has the ol' `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: you could declare one as an auto but it would only persist for that block.

Comment: oh i'm an idiot.. i was doing Myclass obj = new Myclass, even though i know new creates a pointer >< (ALWAYS used new for classes in java). To hell with my principle, gonna use an array. edit: ^^ thanks to both of you for your help

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:
The first and unsafe option is to have

```
private:     
    int* tellers;
```

and in your constructor:

```
tellers = new int[yourParamGoesHere];
```

the second and safer option is to use a vector, you would then have

```
private:
    std::vector<int> tellers;
```

and in your contructor you would do:

```
Office(int numberOfTellers):
    tellers(std::vector<int>(numberOfTellers))
```

And then whenever you want to read or write any of the integers you index the vector like you would an array like so:

```
tellers[0] = 42;
```

Comment: It should be noted that vectors are not completely safe. You can still do stupid things with a vector, albeit it's quite a bit harder.